# Question on class implementation with interface

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have created the following classes for sharing images. They implement an interface, but I need a way of switching between them  with user interaction. I've done it the following way:

[image]

As you can see, service 1 and service 2 implement **iSharingServices**, and inherit from **PolimorphSharing**.

PolimorphSharing is simply and an abstract class that implements the methods I want public from Service 1 and Service 2. Those methods will then be overridden on the Service 1 and Service 2.

Because I need a way to switch the service in runtime, I've created a gateway class that inherits from PolimorphSharing. I can then call it the following way:

```
private var sharingService:PolimorphSharing = new SharingServicesGW('svc1').createService();
```

This all works flawlessly, and I can now switch between services with no problem whatsoever. However, I feel there's something wrong about it, so I would like to ask you guys for some advice on how to better implement this.

Any opinions here would be appreciated. I feel like I'm kind of implementing the **factory pattern** here the hard way.

**UPDATE:**
Just adding some more insight to this. Basically the idea here is for my client to be able to upload images with various different public sharing services such as imageshack, imgur etc. I want my client to be able to select the service in which the image is to be published to (hence the "*switching between them  with user interaction*" bit of the question.

The method that does the uploading bit, is requestShareImage(), **processResults()** simply turns whatever gets returned to a unique format, so my client can read off it always the same way. **getObject()** is my accessor, and onIOError will handle exceptions with any of the public API's

Thanks all in advance,

Comment: Looks fine to me, I can't think of any other pattern that would be more suitable.

Comment: I could be wrong, but maybe you could have `PolimorphSharing`(maybe rename that to `SharingService`) implement `iSharingService`(`ISharingService`*), then `Service1` and `Service2` will only have to extend `PolimorphSharing`. Also `iSharingService` could just have `requestShareImage()` and `getObject()` defined as methods to be implemented by subclasses and then `PolimorphSharing` can declare the `processResults()` and `onIOError()` event handlers as abstract methods.

Comment: Will give it a try and get back here

Comment: @Marcos Placona can you go into more detail about the purpose of each class and their methods as well as the overall purpose your project. I think your question is really interesting +1

Comment: @Taurayi added more information, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharingServicesGW *IS* a factory. However, there's no need for it to - and it shouldn't - inherit from PolimorphSharing. Also you're doing it a bit skewed. The client should be using objects of the interface type, not the abstract type.
Your interface should be defining the public API, not your abstract base class. In fact in AS3 interfaces can only define public members, while pseudo abstract classes can enforce implementation of protected members.

-- EDIT --

here's a UML diagram of how I would do it
[image]

Comment: Yes, i agree with that, but i find that if the client use objects of the interface type, I can do things like "addEventListener", and I can't switch between objects as I described above. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Ha, I accepted by mistake.... Have taken it out though... Would appreciate seeing your take on it

Comment: @Marcos Placona I didn't mean you had to unacept I just meant it was a shame the question was closed already, I still would have posted my answer. Anyway I'm still working on it but some of what Creynders said I agree with.

Comment: I really didn't "unacept" because of that. I did because I initially accepted by mistake, since I still had questions (as you can see above) about @Creynders' answer, and was really only going to accept anything once all my questions were clarified. Hope he understands accepting it so "prematurely" was a genuine mistake

Comment: You meant you *can't* use addEventListener if it's of the interface type?
That's not a problem, just let the interface inherit from IEventDispatcher.
And why wouldn't you be able to switch objects in exactly the same way?

Comment: +1 yh this answer was pretty much what my answer was going to be except with a working example. All in all this is the best approach to go with, except I would let `ASharingService` implement `ISharingService` and `IEventDispatcher` instead of `ISharingService` extend `IEventDispatcher` and then `ASharingService` extend `ISharingService`.

Comment: @Taurayi: if ISharingService doesn't inherit from IEventDispatcher, he'll be casting the concrete service instances back and forth between both interfaces. There's no real reason not to let ISharingService inherit IEventDispatcher, since it's an integral part of the services functionality.

Comment: I'll have a play with it tonight and see if it all still works. Will get back to you guys, but thanks in advance, this solution seems more robust than what I architected, as it gives me more flexibility

Comment: @Creynders that's why he would on have to cast it to `ASharingService` which implements both interfaces.

Comment: @Taurayi: yes, but the whole idea of interfaces is to decouple functionality from implementation. When casting to ASharingService he'd be coupling the client to that specific implementation.
Let's say for instance a third service needs to be added, that doesn't need the abstract base class, then he'll be in trouble. Probably he *will* let it inherit from the abstract class, but that's really bad programming.

Comment: Let's turn it around: why wouldn't ISharingService extend IEventDispatcher?
The only reason I can imagine is to facilitate the possibility of swapping messaging system. For instance from events to signals.
But A/ that wouldn't be possible when casting to ASharingService either without the same amount of refactoring. B/it's a fringe case, since events are bakedin into the language, in other words, they're always available even if one would decide to swap the rest of the system to signals C/the only solution would be to create a messaging facade interface with adapters.

Comment: @Creynders I would have thought if he didn't want that third service to implement `IEventDispatcher` then `ISharingService` extending `IEventDispatcher` forcing any concrete implementation of `ISharingService` to implement `IEventDispatcher` would be bad programming, but I could be wrong, what you said made sense.